# Domaincontroller not forwarding dns requests

Tags: networking, dns, windows-domain

I've setup a test environment that looks like:

- modem/router connected to physical host
- hyper-v manager running on physical host
- Virtual Switch connected to external network
- Two VMs (DC + client) connected to virtual switch

The DC has the following static config:

- IP: 192.168.1.100
- Subn: 255.255.255.0
- Gateway: 192.168.1.1
- DNS 127.0.0.1
- External DNS 8.8.8.8 added to 'Forwarders' within DNS Management.

Client config:

- IP: 192.168.1.101
- Subn: 255.255.255.0
- Gateway: 192.168.1.100
- DNS: 192.168.1.100

Facts:

- Client can ping router and DC
- DC can ping router, cannot ping client
- DC has internet, client does not

To my limited understanding the DNS query from the client should by forwarded by my DC to either the router (192.168.1.1 or google dns 8.8.8.8). It seems to do neither. Is the fact that i'm using a single NIC for all machines (physical and virtual) related to the problems im having?

Comment: The gateway on the client should, in normal situations, be the same as on the DC. Both DC and client are in the same subnet. If the modem/router is 192.168.1.1 then use that as gateway from both machines. After that the first thing to test is: is there internet connectivity from the DC. Can you resolve DNS queries from the DC? The installation being virtual and sharing hardware should not be an issue. In this setup the client should use DC for DNS queries. The DC get's the info asked from it's cache or queries upstream (8.8.8.8) to get the info requested

Comment: Setting the client gw to same address as DC didn't work at first which made me doubt. Apparantly the VPN on my physical host messed up NAT. Thanks for sending me in the right direction.